# Create a controllers API using Javascript and Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, controller

i'm new at creating a REST API Controller using Javascript, i have a project that should put a API to controllers API Groups, but i got a confuse which code should i put at controllers and which code should i put at a services from my API code, here is a code where its has to be my API code.

index.js

```
...
const transporter = mail.createTransport({
  service: service,
  host: host,
  auth: {
    user: user,
    pass: pass
  }
});

router.post('/', routing.requireAuth, (req, res, next) => {
  
  validator.validateBody(req, {
    'fullName': {
      notEmpty: true
    },
    'site': {
      notEmpty: true
    },
    'email': {
      notEmpty: true
    },
    'phone': {
      notEmpty: true
    },
    'subject': {
      notEmpty: true,
      in: {
        option: [subject]
      }
    },
    'description': {
      notEmpty: true
    },
    'type': {
      notEmpty: true
    }
  }, (err) => {
    if(Err.invalidInput(next,err)) { return; }
      var fullName = req.body.fullName;
      var site = req.body.site;
      var email = req.body.email;
      var phone = req.body.phone;
      var subject = req.body.subject;
      var description = req.body.description;
      var type = req.body.type;
      const content = 'Name : ' + fullName + '\nSite : ' + site + '\nContact : ' + phone + '\nMessage : ' + description;
  
      const mailOptions = {
        from: fullName + '<' + email + '>',
        to: sendTo,
        replyTo: email,
        subject: type + ':' + subject,
        text: content
      };

      transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err) => {
        if(Err.unexpected(next, err)) { return; }
        
        res.status(201)
          .json(req.body)
          .end();
      });
    })
  });

module.exports = router;
```

Can, somebody help me? Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

you have to create two folders one is for routes and one is controllers

in route folder create `user_routes.js` or `user.js` file and add code like this

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const UserController = require("../controller/users_controller.js");

router.get("/Signup", UserController.Signup);
other routes related to users
```

in controllers create `users_controller.js` and add code

```
module.exports = {

Signup :  async (req, res) => {
 validator.validateBody(req, {
'fullName': {
  notEmpty: true
},
'site': {
  notEmpty: true
},
'email': {
  notEmpty: true
},
'phone': {
  notEmpty: true
},
'subject': {
  notEmpty: true,
  in: {
    option: [subject]
  }
},
'description': {
  notEmpty: true
},
'type': {
  notEmpty: true
  }
  }, (err) => {
  if(Err.invalidInput(next,err)) { return; }
  var fullName = req.body.fullName;
  var site = req.body.site;
  var email = req.body.email;
  var phone = req.body.phone;
  var subject = req.body.subject;
  var description = req.body.description;
  var type = req.body.type;
  const content = 'Name : ' + fullName + '\nSite : ' + site + '\nContact : ' + phone + 
'\nMessage : ' + description;

  const mailOptions = {
    from: fullName + '<' + email + '>',
    to: sendTo,
    replyTo: email,
    subject: type + ':' + subject,
    text: content
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err) => {
    if(Err.unexpected(next, err)) { return; }
    
    res.status(201)
      .json(req.body)
      .end();
  });
})
 }
}
```

imort files and helpers you required to sinup user

Comment: In my routes folder is has a controllers API already, what shoul i do, if there a controllers api in my routes folder?

Comment: i have told you exactly that you which code you have have to remove and where to add that code